# I installed the scrapy on my windows but while creating a project ,I got error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I installed the lxml2 lib from unofficial Windows binaries (lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl). After that, I installed the scrapy successfully. But while creating a project using

- scrapy startproject tutorial
  I got an error
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1, in init lxml.etree
  ValueError: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 904 from C header, got 896 from PyObject

-I tried to install several versions of the lxml file but was unable to install another version of lxml2
[image]

- installed scrapy success
- unable to start scrapy project

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Alexander  I am using python version 3.11.0a3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is not any code. I installed Scrapy. But unable to create a project. While creating a project I got an error which is mentioned above.

Comment: The problem is solved I change the python version , previously - 3.11.0a3 changed to 3.8.8

Comment: @AkashKarmacharya  Changing to python 3.10 would have been sufficient. but I am glad you figured it out